# Hazelcast in Docker in boot2docker "Error while fetching cluster partition table"

Tags: java, docker, hazelcast, boot2docker

My setup: an [Hazelcast docker container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/looztra/deb-hazelcast/) running in a boot2docker vm (hosted on windows, and yes, port 5701 is forwarded).
That's Hazelcast 3.4.2.

When I try to connect a simple java client to this hazelcast instance, I get a:

```
avr. 01, 2015 10:52:03 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFOS: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test][3.4.2] is STARTING
avr. 01, 2015 10:52:04 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFOS: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test][3.4.2] is STARTED
avr. 01, 2015 10:52:06 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFOS: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test][3.4.2] is CLIENT_CONNECTED
avr. 01, 2015 10:52:06 PM     com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread
INFOS: 

Members [1] {
    Member [172.17.42.1]:5701
}

avr. 01, 2015 10:53:46 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.ClientPartitionService
GRAVE: Error while fetching cluster partition table!
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at     com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl.getOrConnect(Cli    entConnectionManagerImpl.java:337)
...

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get initial partitions!
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.getInitialPartitions(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:89)
at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClientPartitionServiceImpl.start(ClientPartitionServiceImpl.java:65)
at com.hazelcast.client.impl.HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.start(HazelcastClientInstanceImpl.java:189)
at ...
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:35 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread
AVERTISSEMENT: Error while listening cluster events! -> ClientConnection{live=true, writeHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientWriteHandler@3a2f22ed, readHandler=com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientReadHandler@6b7cdede, connectionId=1, socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:64753 remote=/127.0.0.1:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=Address[172.17.42.1]:5701}, Error: java.io.EOFException: Remote socket closed!
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:35 PM com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection
AVERTISSEMENT: Connection [null] lost. Reason: Socket explicitly closed
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:35 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFOS: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test][3.4.2] is CLIENT_DISCONNECTED
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:43 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread
AVERTISSEMENT: Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 1 of 2.
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:50 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread
AVERTISSEMENT: Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 0 ms later, attempt 2 of 2.
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:50 PM com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread
GRAVE: Error while connecting to cluster!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to connect to any address in the config! The following addresses were tried:[/127.0.0.1:5701, /172.17.42.1:5701, /127.0.0.1:5702, /127.0.0.1:5703]
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread.connectToOne(ClusterListenerThread.java:286)
    at com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerThread.run(ClusterListenerThread.java:89)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.connect(SocketAdaptor.java:111)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionProcessor.call(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:386)
    at com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$ConnectionProcessor.call(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.CompletableFutureTask.run(CompletableFutureTask.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)

avr. 01, 2015 10:56:50 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFOS: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test][3.4.2] is SHUTTING_DOWN
avr. 01, 2015 10:56:50 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFOS: HazelcastClient[hz.client_0_test][3.4.2] is SHUTDOWN
```

To sum up: the client seems to see the cluster and its member, but something happens next that prevent the connection to work as expected.

Any idea?

Comment: Some more context: this is related to the java client, the REST client works perfectly in the same usecase

Comment: Did you forward the port on the windows host, in boot2docker and and EXPOSEed in Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is, that the internal and external address of the Hazelcast node are different and the node, even though it can be reached due to NAT, rejects to take a request on the public address.
You can configure the public address using the configuration: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/manual/html-single/hazelcast-documentation.html#public-address (see example above).

Comment: I already tried something like that with no luck (but I will try again).

Comment: So in my case, I have to set the public address to the ip of the boot2docker vm (something like 10.0.2.15) even if the container does not bind this IP?        Does not work for me with the configuration and logs available at https://gist.github.com/looztra/c1e3f6256642a3067961

Comment: Yeah you definately have a different problem since your client can connect, is authorized and got the member address. This is weird. Can you add the server source as well?

Comment: I updated the content of the gist with some infos. The server is started thanks to https://gist.github.com/looztra/c1e3f6256642a3067961#file-hazelcast-start-server-sh i.e. just a call to the provided com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer

Comment: Hello I'm facing the same problem, I didnt quite understand how you resolved. Could you please help me ...I'm not able to figure out how i can open hazel-server.sh on my  docker console?

Comment: nothing resolved yet. An option is to use the rest client. To be noted: no problem if you're trying to communicate with the hazelcast server container from another container (on the same host)

Comment: I had the same problem with a docker-machine VM on a Mac and Hazelcast 3.3.5. Setting <public-address> in hazelcast.xml to the IP of my docker-machine VM fixed it.